# Facebook Graph API: how to send chat message to all members of a group

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get all members of a group and send them all a chat message (rather than a group post as the chat message 'pops' up for the users so they can see it easily.)

I am using the `<group_id>/members` API (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/workplace/integrations/custom-integrations/reference/group) edge to return the members ID and Name but I am unable to use this ID in the `me/messages` SEND API (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages).  It looks like I need to get the users page-scoped ID but I do not know how to do that, or indeed if there are any other (better) approaches i could look at.

Answer (score 0):

You can only send messages from Pages to Users, and only if they initiated the conversation (so they specifically authorized your Page to send them a message). There is no API to send messages from User to User or from Group to User, and of course there is no way to send messages to all members of a Group. That would be pure spam.